# I need to list properties of a Get-UnifiedGroup command including one array

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a report for all our MS Teams groups including relevant parameters like `name`, `groupid`, when was it changed for a last time, AND (which is the core of my problem) people that are managing the Team.

But, "ManagedBy" is displayed as an array (which it is), so the result is truncated (in most cases). How do I make a list of various properties, display them "fully" when one of them is an array?

What I get when listing the group is something like that:

```
get-unifiedgroup -Identity 1234-xxxyyy-5678-aaabbb | select displayname, whenchanged, managedby
```

```
DisplayName   WhenChanged            ManagedBy
-----------   -----------            ---------
GroupOne      9/26/2019 6:50:40 AM   {Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Name5...}
```

Not much code to show, its just a simple command above...

Expected result is to have a full "list" out of that array, something that you do with `select -ExpandProperty`... but this is not applicable when you are trying to list multiple properties.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you store the group object in a variable and then reference the property?

```
$Group = get-unifiedgroup -Identity 1234-xxxyyy-5678-aaabbb
$Group.ManagedBy
```

Though if your end goal is to create a report (CSV file?), if you output what you have, the entire array will show up. It only gets truncated in the console, but the full array value is still there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - but, simply putting it into csv will not show all values, but keep them the same way as they are in powershell screen (and, for some reason it will not even display all properties I wanted to "select" but just first three) - and when I do it like you suggested it works for one particular group, but for a list of all these groups I dont know how to use it...

Comment: Hmm okay. For outputting to a CSV, typically I create a new [PSCustomObject] for each object, e.g. `$GroupObj = [PSCustomObject]@{ DisplayName=$Group.DisplayName; WhenChanged = $Group.WhenChanged; ManagedBy = $Group.ManagedBy }`. And if the above code works for one group, for a list of groups you can just do a foreach loop.